# Why is the answer on this question not being shown?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

I asked the following question approximately one year ago,

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760219/what-is-the-difference-between-php7-and-php5*

It has approximately 50k views and 40+ upvotes.

There was one answer of this question with approx 80+ upvotes, but that answer is not being shown, and now **instead a white space is shown there**. **I don't know why and how it removed?** Can anyone explain please?

I think so there should be some lock mechanism, meaning if a question has an answer with such a high reputation it should not be deletable or so.

Due to this, viewers of question are downvoting the question and getting the wrong impression.

Comment: The question was already closed as _too broad__. You are doing yourself no favors by shining a light into your question I'm afraid.

Comment: BTW, is an upvoted but closed question with no answers eligible for Roomba?

Comment: Yes that is what my point is, now this is a closed question with no answer and 40+ upvotes, is it make sense?

Comment: What doesn't make any sense is this question surviving long enough to get 40 upvotes.

Comment: i think so it was getting up votes because of nice answer, BTW no one can stop someone to up vote a question.

Comment: I asked question here and everyone downvoted my question is what i got from meta community.

Comment: @ImranQamer It's called "the Meta effect". You've drawn attention to your question. And since it's a question that is textbook off-topic, it now gets downvotes. Sorry, but "what is the future of PHP7" cannot be answered objectively. The question was popular, but it was never a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: But, if it makes you feel a little better: many people encounter the Meta effect. You're not alone.

Comment: That's what I meant about you doing yourself no favors by drawing attention to your question. Your question was going to get downvotes once it got the eye of certain type of SO user. Still, since it has a positive score (yet), I'm not sure if Roomba will get it.

Comment: Then you mean i should not drawn attention of community to a question which has 40+ upvotes with no answer. I think so moderator should not delete those answers which has so many upvotes or they should have some other mechanism

Comment: Apparently your question was deleted already. But be happy, since it was deleted you'll receive no more downvotes, and since the question was old I think you get to keep your "earned" rep.

Comment: I am still not happy as i am pointing out an issue and no one here is actually getting my point and defending the functionality. About repo its nothing to me instead knowlege and a strong community

Comment: You *were* complaining about getting downvotes "unfairly". Don't say otherwise now. And I think that people got your point. But most people who saw your question now didn't think very highly about it. You were just lucky to fly under the radar for time. IMO, by losing this question nothing of value was lost. There are hundreds of articles and posts covering that subject with varying depths. Not only it was overly broad, but it was extremely simple to research.

Answer (score 5):

The answer was deleted by a moderator because its content is plagiarised from [here](http://www.appsntech.com/2015/04/5-best-things-you-should-know-about-php.html).

> Hi Shammas, thanks for the great answer. By the way, somehow I find the same article here: [appsntech.com/2015/04/…](http://www.appsntech.com/2015/04/5-best-things-you-should-know-about-php.html) Did you forget to cite the source, or are they taking the content from SO? If it is the first case, it would be nice to refer to the original post. If it is the 2nd case, you can report it here: [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do) – Hoàng Long Feb 3 at 10:10

> Do not copy content from elsewhere without clear attribution. It is seen as plagiarism. See stackoverflow.com/help/referencing – Matt♦ Mar 10 at 12:59

Comment: **Note**: Comments removed - please keep comments related to this question and answer only.