# Do plagiarists get to keep reputation if plagiarism is discovered late enough?

Tags: bug, reputation, plagiarism

We all know reputation points aren't a  solid measure of ability or anything like that. They're arbitrary and imaginary points.

On the other hand, reputation is not *nothing*. SO actively touts it as an indicator of ability in the context of its Jobs site. Moderation tools are made available to users based on reputation. And even though they're imaginary, they are the only tangible reward for many users' hard work.

In light of that, is it really OK that plagiarists get to keep ill-gotten reputation if their plagiarism is discovered late enough - so the rule preventing rep loss from deletion if the content is more than 3 months old (IIRC) kicks in?

Case in point: [this user.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349788/shammas-pk)

His visible contributions amount to 101 points. Yet he has 1,105 - presumably because it was eventually discovered their entire body of work was plagiarized, the posts deleted, but the reputation preserved because the content was considered old. (The one +9 answer that survived the purge I just flagged as plagiarism, too.)

If this is the norm, then there is no deterrent to plagiarism at all. You can copy & paste as you please, and then just hope that no one notices for 3 months, which is probably the norm. Once you get caught, you let moderators delete  the offending post, wait out a possible suspension, and voilá - you have a squeaky clean account with hundreds, thousands, or tens of thousands of points.

Comment: I fail to see how this is a bug.  This is a feature request.  It's also not clear how, specifically, you would like this to be addressed.

Comment: In such high-vote cases, we can simply remove the post from their account, which will remove all the reputation as well. It's not as if they exactly own the post that removing it from their account is bothersome. But users keeping large amounts of reputation due to plagiarism is pretty rare.

Comment: @animuson Would dissociating the post from the account make it harder for mods to see a history of problematic content from the user, for example a history of plagiarism?

Comment: @animuson if the example I found is an exception rather than the norm, then I guess all is well.

Comment: @Servy No, not really. We have a record of who the post used to be belong to, and a list of annotations created explicitly for recording this kind of thing.

Comment: @Servy `It's also not clear how, specifically, you would like this to be addressed.` I guess I'm asking for a "nuke" deletion feature that does not preserve the rep - or alternatively disassociates the posts altogether as animuson says.

Comment: Question taken from my case asked here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345454/why-answer-on-this-question-is-not-being-shown?noredirect=1#comment456763_345454

Comment: @servy We can see those posts in the user history if we check. So that's fine.

Comment: [This sounds familiar...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336392/you-get-to-keep-reputation-from-plagiarized-posts-if-they-arent-discovered-with)

Comment: Pure plagiarism @BoltClock ...

Comment: @Boltclock arrrgh! I was *certain* I had posted about this before, but couldn't find it. Vote to close as duplicate, then, I suppose.....

Comment: @Bart: It's not, because he used his own wor-- oh.

Comment: @Bart Little does he suspect that Meta doesn't give reputation :-D

Comment: If I don't get to keep 8 upvotes from this question, though, I'm going to *sue*.

Comment: @Pekka 웃: Bookmark this page and you'll know where exactly to find those 8 upvotes anytime.

Comment: @animuson maybe you could post an answer to either this question, or the duplicate one? Your comment seems to resolve the issue (because it explains that things aren't as bad as they look after all.)

Comment: Seeing a huge "That solved my problem!" button on top now. Should I click it? This is exciting.

Comment: @Pekka웃 just don't forget to ask again in 6 months (having said that - maybe you will) :p

Comment: @Jon it's happened to me a number of times that I would painstakingly write up a Meta post about an annoying bug or a feature suggestion, only to then find out I wrote the same thing two years ago. I find it more reassuring than worrying, though - shows that your mind really works somewhat consistently. :)

Comment: Well and it shows that no one seem to care/there is no time for this/the decision processes are pretty slow. And that's quite sad, because I agree with you :(.

Comment: @Tom That's true for some issues, but not for this particular one.  The mods don't need any additional tools to deal with this issue; they already have all of the tools that they need.

Comment: @Servy If this is the case, then one of the mods should write a proper answer so the request/question won't remain unsolved/hanging in midair. animuson did that for Pekkas original question a few moments ago.

Comment: @Tom It was answered in comments.  Anyone could have written up an answer at any time if they would have wanted to; the information was available.